# How can I use a curve node to shape the edge of this node texture?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, bump

I'm really struggling to understand why the curves layer isn't creating rounded edges in this shader. My goal is to control the shape of tile edges with a curve node (to achieve custom/rounded edges), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Here's the basic setup:**

[image]

Adjusting the Bump node's Distance value sort of resolves the issue, but that lowers the bump's visual effectiveness. Is there a way to achieve strong highlights/shadows and get a smooth, custom edge?

Edit: Also, how would one get ride of these hard edges at the corners?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your big brains and generosity!

Answer (score 1):

Bump maps can be tricky but the distance on yours is way too high.  Basically no matter how you ramp the color it's trying to give it the appearance of jutting way out.

[image]

I decreased to .008 and then I was able to get finer control out of the curve node.

[image]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I ended up doing exactly that, but I'm still curious why the bump node tries so hard to make everything intense. Regardless, thanks for taking time to offer your help! <3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that value is in blender units.

Comment: I can't tell if that's suppose to be a joke. I'm super new to all this... heh